# How to create shared JDBC connection to use on executors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created spark jdbc singleton connection in driver & planning to use connection in executors. I get below exception. org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Inside spark main class:

```
object ExecutorConnection {
      private var connection: Connection = null
      val url = prop.getProperty("url")
      val user = prop.getProperty("user")
      val pwd = prop.getProperty("password")
      val driver = prop.getProperty("driver")
      Class.forName(driver)
     def getConnection(url: String, username: String, password: String): Connection = synchronized {
        if (connection == null) {
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
          Class.forName(driver)
          connection.setAutoCommit(false)
        }
        connection
      }
      lazy val createConnection = getConnection(url, user, pwd)
    }
```

I have multiple dataframes(df1,df2,df3) with different schema , where im planning to create connection in driver level & serialize the connection & use it for all dataframes.

```
  df1.rdd.repartition(2).mapPartitions((d) => Iterator(d)).foreach { partition =>    
    val conn = ExecutorConnection.createConnection 
    var ps: PreparedStatement = null
    partition.grouped(1).foreach(batch => {
      batch.foreach { x =>
        {
          ps = conn.prepareStatement(SqlString)
          ps.addBatch()
          conn.commit()
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: I think you should call foreach partition instead of foreach after mapPartitions. Basically, your mapPartitions is doing nothing and then you are going through records, not partitions. You cannot serialize connection, only create it from scratch at workers.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Dataset.foreachPartition](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset):

> **foreachPartition(f: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit**
>
> Applies a function f to each partition of this Dataset.

This trick with Scala object is exactly how you get the connection once per task (and I think per executor also).

```
df1.foreachPartition { vs =>
  // use the connection here
}
```

Use [Guava](https://guava.dev/) for a cache.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> where im planning to create connection in driver level & serialize the connection

It does not work that way.

You have to create connections on executor else you will keep getting this exception.

Comment: Not sure if I understand why -1 for this answer?